# Traffic Light Simulation Trouble

Tags: vb.net

I have a project for school in which I must simulate a set of traffic lights at a four-way intersection, so two lights must work in conjunction with each other and have a small delay before switching to next set of lights. I have this ~98% done but can't seem to get my red lights to function. As it stands, my green lights and yellow lights function as expected, with the exception that after the light is yellow, it returns to green...
I'm not sure where I went wrong here, especially considering the yellow lights work. Any pointers would be very appreciated, Thank you!

```
Public Class frmTraffic

Dim NS As Boolean = False
Dim EW As Boolean = False

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click

    'Set North/South boolean to true and call the Sub for it
    NS = True
    NSLights()

End Sub

Private Sub btnStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStop.Click

    'Add each light and timer object to a collection for ease of use
    Dim lights() = {L1Green, L1Yellow, L1Red, L2Green, L2Yellow, L2Red, L3Green, L3Yellow, L3Red, L4Green, _
                    L4Yellow, L4Red}

    Dim timers() = {tmrDelay, tmrGreen, tmrRed, tmrYellow}

    'Disable all timers
    For Each tmr In timers
        tmr.Enabled = False
    Next
    'Return all lights to default system color
    For Each light In lights
        light.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrYellow.Tick

    tmrGreen.Enabled = False
    NSLights()
    EWLights()
    tmrRed.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub tmrDelay_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrDelay.Tick

    tmrRed.Enabled = False
    NSLights()
    EWLights()
    'Add each light and timer object to a collection for ease of use
    Dim lights() = {L1Green, L1Yellow, L1Red, L2Green, L2Yellow, L2Red, L3Green, L3Yellow, L3Red, L4Green, _
                    L4Yellow, L4Red}
    'Return all lights to default system color
    For Each light In lights
        light.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
    Next
    Swap()

End Sub

Private Sub tmrGreen_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrGreen.Tick

    NSLights()
    EWLights()
    tmrYellow.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub tmrRed_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrRed.Tick

    tmrYellow.Enabled = False
    NSLights()
    EWLights()
    tmrDelay.Enabled = True

End Sub

Sub NSLights()

    'Begin the Traffic light pattern
    If NS = True Then
        tmrDelay.Enabled = False
        tmrGreen.Enabled = True
        L1Yellow.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
        L1Red.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
        L2Yellow.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
        L2Red.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
        L1Green.BackColor = Color.Green
        L2Green.BackColor = Color.Green
        If tmrYellow.Enabled = True Then
            L1Green.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
            L2Green.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
            L1Yellow.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            L2Yellow.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            If tmrRed.Enabled = True Then
                L1Yellow.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
                L2Yellow.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
                L1Red.BackColor = Color.Red
                L2Red.BackColor = Color.Red
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Sub EWLights()

    'Begin the Traffic light pattern
    If EW = True Then
        tmrDelay.Enabled = False
        tmrGreen.Enabled = True
        L3Yellow.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
        L3Red.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
        L4Yellow.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
        L4Red.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
        L3Green.BackColor = Color.Green
        L4Green.BackColor = Color.Green
        If tmrYellow.Enabled = True Then
            L3Green.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
            L4Green.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
            L3Yellow.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            L4Yellow.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            If tmrRed.Enabled = True Then
                L3Yellow.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
                L4Yellow.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
                L3Red.BackColor = Color.Red
                L4Red.BackColor = Color.Red
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Function Swap()

    Dim cond0 = Nothing
    Dim cond1 = NS = True
    Dim cond2 = NS = False
    Dim cond3 = EW = True
    Dim cond4 = EW = False
    Dim x = cond0

    If NS = cond1 Then
        NS = cond2
        x = cond3
        EWLights()
    ElseIf EW = cond3 Then
        EW = cond4
        x = cond1
        NSLights()
    End If

    Return x

End Function
```

End Class

Comment: I would expect something like "If Red Then ... Else If Yellow Then ... Else".  You're not doing that

Comment: you only need one timer with several different *intervals* depending on the state. timers are not that precise and keeping multiples in synch will be problematic.  What is `NorthSouth` - it is an array, but of what?

Comment: @Plutonix, NorthSouth (L1 & L2 groups) is the collection of two lights, as is EastWest (L3 &L4 groups), those however aren't being used. They were from a previous attempt and I forgot to remove them. I'll update the code to reflect that, apologies. I'll also try using a single timer, I have no idea why I thought multiples was the way to go here...

Comment: @paulsm4, I thought that the if statements I have now would have handled that in the same fashion considering the green to yellow transition works...

Comment: Well, have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: @OldProgrammer, I have and the output I get is confusing. It states that some threads have closed due to errors and throws a code, but the Visual Studio error helper says that not enough information is given to determine a cause.

Comment: "'Traffic Lights.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Traffic Lights.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x20dc has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x218 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Remoting\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a **very simple** light system where each state is mutually exclusive of all other states, then consider using an [Enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to represent the current direction and state of each light, and a **single** Timer as suggested by Plutonix.

Here's a quick example:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Enum IntersectionDirectionState
        NorthSouth
        EastWest
    End Enum

    Private Enum TrafficLightState
        Green
        Yellow
        Red
    End Enum

    Private dir As IntersectionDirectionState = IntersectionDirectionState.NorthSouth
    Private NS As TrafficLightState = TrafficLightState.Green
    Private EW As TrafficLightState = TrafficLightState.Red

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        OutputState()
        Timer1.Interval = 2000
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OutputState()
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("dir: {0}, NS: {1}, EW: {2}", dir, NS, EW))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Select Case dir
            Case IntersectionDirectionState.NorthSouth
                Select Case NS
                    Case TrafficLightState.Green
                        NS = TrafficLightState.Yellow

                    Case TrafficLightState.Yellow
                        NS = TrafficLightState.Red

                    Case TrafficLightState.Red
                        dir = IntersectionDirectionState.EastWest
                        EW = TrafficLightState.Green

                End Select

            Case IntersectionDirectionState.EastWest
                Select Case EW
                    Case TrafficLightState.Green
                        EW = TrafficLightState.Yellow

                    Case TrafficLightState.Yellow
                        EW = TrafficLightState.Red

                    Case TrafficLightState.Red
                        dir = IntersectionDirectionState.NorthSouth
                        NS = TrafficLightState.Green

                End Select

        End Select
        OutputState()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Output:

```
dir: NorthSouth, NS: Green, EW: Red
dir: NorthSouth, NS: Yellow, EW: Red
dir: NorthSouth, NS: Red, EW: Red
dir: EastWest, NS: Red, EW: Green
dir: EastWest, NS: Red, EW: Yellow
dir: EastWest, NS: Red, EW: Red
dir: NorthSouth, NS: Green, EW: Red
dir: NorthSouth, NS: Yellow, EW: Red
dir: NorthSouth, NS: Red, EW: Red
dir: EastWest, NS: Red, EW: Green
```

I'll leave it up to you to update the User Interface to display the correct state, and also change the `Interval` of the Timer to make different delays at each stage of the cycle.

With this approach, you could add to the directions enum to handle protected left turns, for instance (you'd need another variable(s) to track that light state just like "NS" and "EW").  You could also handle a weird 3-way intersection with this approach.

If the light states overlapped, like a left turn light that had a different length and/or start time than going straight, then a completely different approach to the problem would probably be better.

Comment: Thank you for the point to enums. It's odd that in an advanced course at college level, the text makes no mention of these methods. So much of this language isn't touched upon in the course and when I come here there's a multitude of ways to do what I was trying. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm always amazed at how little programming a Computer Science Graduate actually learns and knows (assuming they had no programming experience beforehand).  To be fair, the focus really should be on how to break down problems, analyze complexity, develop algorithms, and represent data.  Implementation is language specific, which has the drawback of making the student get bogged down in details that don't necessarily translate into making a better coder (in fact, they cloud the issue of **solving the problem**).  Deciding which language constructs to teach falls into the same category...

Comment: ...giving the student too many options makes it hard to focus on the problem.  When ever you can, solve the problem first, without the User Interface as I did above.  Then "make it pretty" afterwards.  Good luck!

Comment: I absolutely agree. It also doesn't help that there is practically no explanation of the code in this text either, it simply gives you a very basic program as an example then tells you to complete something it doesn't touch on for another few chapters, if at all.